# My environment texture is not displaying

Tags: world

[image]

I have enable equirectangular, pressed 5, not sure why this is happening. Please help.

Comment: IN node editor In the properties you don't have source file. click the reload (turning arrow)

Comment: If not load the above the source file click the cross button to delete the properties and in the environment load the image

Comment: Adding the image to the source file actually worked! thank you so much!